# How to convert a Phantom signature to string in order to pas it via API?

Tags: javascript, phantom, signature, decode, signing

I have a signature from the Phantom wallet in the Uint8Array format which I receive in the following way.

```
const encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode("sign me please");
const signedMessage = await provider.signMessage(encodedMessage, "utf8");
```

I need to serialise/convert this signature as a string so that I can pass it via an API.

**Problem**:

I have tried using TextDecoder like this:

```
const decodedSignature = new TextDecoder().decode(signedMessage.signature);
```

however if I try to encode it back, I get a Uint8Array that contains different bytes that the original signature:

```
// the result is different from signedMessage.signature
const encodedSignature = new TextEncoder().encode(decodedSignature);
```

**Question**:

How can I convert a Phantom wallet signature to string an back in order to pass it via API calls?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to base64

```
const base64str = Buffer.from(signedMessage).toString('base64');
```

At the backend just decode base64 string back to u8 array.